# Compressing file to Zip file using PHP on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zip, compression, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to compress txt file to a zip file stored on a Google Cloud storage bucket.

I've written a function below which works on local files, but not on files stored on the cloud bucket.

I suspect the problem is the `ZipArchive` class, however, the [1.8.9 App Engine release notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) indicate that the zip extension is now supported.

```
function CompressFile($inputFilePath, $ZipArchivePath, $fileNameinArchive)
{
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  $zip->open($ZipArchivePath,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
  $zip->addFile($inputFilePath, $fileNameinArchive);    
  $zip->close();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work on "files stored on the cloud bucket". You have to compress the files while they are local to the php script.

Comment: Hi Marcell. I have a file stored on the bucket, I then specify a path to the file using gs//.../file.txt. I want to compress this file so that I end up with a zip file in the same directory i.e gs//.../file.zip.

Comment: I see. You need to check how to use ZipArchive with App Engine (I don't know that, sorry). Where did you get the hint to use `gs//...` (and shouldn't it be `gs://`)? That's where I'd start looking.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write gs://.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There are no errors being reported, however I think the $ZipArchivePath is failing to open.